# Why does my virtual destructor executes these many times?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have been practicing with inheritance, and I found that calling the destructor from a base class pointer to an inherited class, results into a strange output, where I find that my destructor executes more times than it should. Resuming my code (**EDIT: Asked for more code**):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B{

public:

    virtual void f(){cout << "f() - B" << endl;}
    virtual void g(){cout << "g() - B" << endl;}
    virtual void h() = 0;
    virtual ~B(){cout << "~B() destructor" << endl;}

protected:

    int b;
};

class D1: virtual public B{

public:

    void f(){cout << "f() - D1" << endl;}
    virtual void g(){cout << "g() - D1" << endl;}
    virtual ~D1(){cout << "~D1() destructor" << endl;}

protected:

    int d1;
};

class D2: virtual public B{

public:

    void f(int i){cout << "f(" << i << ") - D2" << endl;}
    virtual void h(){cout << "h() - D2" << endl;}
    virtual ~D2(){cout << "~D2() destructor" << endl;}

protected:

    int d2;
};

class D3: public D1{

public:
    void g(){cout << "g() - D3" << endl;}
    void h(){cout << "h() - D3" << endl;}

private:

    int d3;
};

class D4: public D1, public D2{

public:

    using D1::f; using D2::f;

    virtual ~D4(){cout << "~D4() destructor" << endl;}

private:

    int d4;
};

void f(B& b){

   cout << "f() out " << endl;
   b.f();
   b.g();
   b.h();
};

int main()
{
    B *pB;
    D2 d2;
    D3 d3;
    D4 d4;
    f(d2);
    f(d3);
    f(d4);
    d4.D1::f();
    d4.f(5);
    d4.f(3.7);
    d4.g();
    d4.h();
    pB = new D4;
    pB -> f();
    dynamic_cast<D4*>(pB)->f(3);
    pB -> g();
    pB -> h();
    delete pB;
}
```

The final output is:

```
//Other tests
.
.
.
f(3) - D2
~D4() destructor
~D2() destructor
~D1() destructor
~B()  destructor
~D4() destructor
~D2() destructor
~D1() destructor
~B()  destructor
~D1() destructor
~B()  destructor
~D2() destructor
~B()  destructor
```

Creation of pB pointer; points to new D4 object; explicit call to D4 f() method and delete call. I was expecting just four `destructor`calls; one for each inherited class (**D4,D2,D1**) and last one for base class (**B**).

Should these results be normal? Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: The output provided here does not match the code that is shown.  See this [live demo](http://ideone.com/HTQaZG). Based on the output, your test is clearly creating 2 `D4` objects, a `D1` object, and a `D2` object. Your example code is not doing that.

Comment: I added all my code now. Didn't want to because I think a lot of it, it's irrelevant @RemyLebeau

Comment: I'm stupid. I thought my destructor would only delete the one it was pointing, when actually it deletes every inherited + base object coming from the base class. Am I right? @RemyLebeau

Comment: @xFunkyTImes For future reference, please don't post all the code. Post a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're not stupid, but I'm confused. You said in your post " I was expecting just four destructorcalls; one for each inherited class (D4,D2,D1) and last one for base class (B).", and that is 100% correct and what is happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you provided splits out the following output:

```
f(3) - D2
~D4() destructor
~D2() destructor
~D1() destructor
~B() destructor
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/HTQaZG)

You're right to expect 4 destructor calls. `~D4()->~D2()->~D1()->~B()`

But judging from your output, you are actually deleting two `D4` objects, one `D1` object, and another `D2` object.

**Update:**

The destructor is called when

1. You call delete on an object.
2. It goes out of scope.

Now to illustrate my point I am going to introduce a custom scope:

```
int main()
{
    B *pB;
    { // custom scope
        D2 d2;
        D3 d3;
        D4 d4;
        f(d2);
        f(d3);
        f(d4);
        d4.D1::f();
        d4.f(5);
        d4.f(3.7);
        d4.g();
        d4.h();
        pB = new D4;
        pB->f();
        dynamic_cast<D4*>(pB)->f(3);
        pB->g();
        pB->h();
    }
    delete pB;
}
```

Calling this will print the following output:

```
//function calls
~D4() destructor <-- inside custom scope
~D2() destructor <-- inside custom scope
~D1() destructor <-- inside custom scope
~B() destructor  <-- inside custom scope
~D1() destructor <-- inside custom scope
~B() destructor  <-- inside custom scope
~D2() destructor <-- inside custom scope
~B() destructor  <-- inside custom scope
~D4() destructor <-- outside custom scope
~D2() destructor <-- outside custom scope
~D1() destructor <-- outside custom scope
~B() destructor  <-- outside custom scope
```

Comment: I didn't thought rest of my tests were relevant, and I didn't want to write that much code in my question. Now it's all of it + tests.

Comment: I'm stupid. I thought my destructor would only delete the one it was pointing, when actually it deletes every inherited + base object coming from the base class. Am I right? @Shiro

Answer (score 1):

You have `D2`, `D3`, and `D4` objects allocated on the stack, and a `D4` object allocated on the heap.  You are seeing output from the `D1`, `D2`, and `D4` destructors (you are not outputting anything in the `D3` destructor).

Do you think `delete` is the only way a destructor gets called?  It is not, but it seems that is what you are thinking.  You are going to get output messages for destructors for all 4 of the objects you created.  The objects on the stack are destructed automatically (in reverse order of creation) when they go out of scope at the end of `main()`. The object on the heap is destructed when you explicitly call `delete` on it:

```
// when you delete pB...
~D4() destructor
~D2() destructor
~D1() destructor
~B()  destructor

// when d4 goes out of scope...
~D4() destructor
~D2() destructor
~D1() destructor
~B()  destructor

// when d3 goes out of scope...
~D1() destructor
~B()  destructor

// when d2 goes out of scope...
~D2() destructor
~B()  destructor
```

See this [live demo](http://ideone.com/5TxNlp), it has the same destructor output you have shown.

This might have been more apparent had you added output to `D3`'s destructor:

```
class D3: public D1{

public:
    void g(){cout << "g() - D3" << endl;}
    void h(){cout << "h() - D3" << endl;}

    virtual ~D3(){cout << "~D3() destructor" << endl;} // <-- add this!

private:

    int d3;
};
```

```
// when d3 goes out of scope...
~D3() destructor <-- this message now appears
~D1() destructor
~B()  destructor
```